# Cleaning up multiple variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, declaration

I would like to clean up my variable declaration and am wondering if there is a better way to go about it.

Below I have a function that is creating chart data based on the length of an array. I am declaring each array before I am adding the values to them.  I have 4 different areas (pa1-4) and 6 different statuses. I declare a variable for each status for each area, as well as a variable for the total.

```
function jobcharts(data) {

//declaring each variable
var i;
var pa1Sum = [],
    pa1SumComplete = [],
    pa1SumGenSM = [],
    pa1SumQue = [],
    pa1SumInP = [],
    pa1SumFin = [],
    pa1SumOH = [],
    pa2Sum = [],
    pa2SumComplete = [],
    pa2SumGenSM = [],
    pa2SumQue = [],
    pa2SumInP = [],
    pa2SumFin = [],
    pa2SumOH = [](...etc);

//going through all data
for (i = 0; i < data.features.length; i++) {
    var jobArea = data.features[i].properties.JOB;

    if (data.features[i].properties.PRIORITY_AREA === "PA1") {
        pa1Sum.push(data.features[i]);
        if (data.features[i].properties["JOB STATUS"] === "ON HOLD") {
            pa1SumOH.push(data.features[i].properties.JOB);
        } else if (data.features[i].properties["JOB STATUS"] === "Generating SM") {
            pa1SumGenSM.push(data.features[i].properties.JOB);
        } else if (data.features[i].properties["JOB STATUS"] === "Queued") {
            pa1SumQue.push(data.features[i].properties.JOB);
        } else if (data.features[i].properties["JOB STATUS"] === "In Progress") {
            pa1SumInP.push(data.features[i].properties.JOB);
        } else if (data.features[i].properties["JOB STATUS"] === "Final Review") {
            pa1SumFin.push(data.features[i].properties.JOB);
        } else {
            pa1SumComplete.push(data.features[i].properties.JOB);
        } (...etc);
```

I then get the length after the loop finishes and structure the data as needed.

```
function arraytest(array, total) {
    if (array.length > 0) {
        return (Math.round(((array.length) / total.length) * 100));
    } else {
        return "0";
    }
}

var pa1Arr = [arraytest(pa1SumComplete, pa1Sum), arraytest(pa1SumFin, pa1Sum), arraytest(pa1SumInP, pa1Sum), arraytest(pa1SumQue, pa1Sum), arraytest(pa1SumGenSM, pa1Sum), arraytest(pa1SumOH, pa1Sum)];
```

Is there a better way to structure the variables so I do not have 24 declarations at the beginning of my function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, just take the job status and group by that:

```
  const totals = {};
  let count = 0;

   for(const { properties: { ["JOB STATUS"]: status, JOB: job, PRIORITY_AREA: priority } } of data.features) {
     if(priority === "Pa1") {
        count++;
        if(!totals[status])
          totals[status] = [];
        totals[status].push(job);
     }
  }
```

To now get the percentages one could map the objects values:

```
 Object.values(totals).map(entries => entries.length / count * 100);
```

Comment: This is a little more complex than I was expecting, would you mind explaining what is happening in your code snippet?

Comment: @zacharyzac thats actually just an object with properties containing arrays that gets filled in a loop. The loop used object destructuring but thats just for beautifying the code a bit.

Comment: Thank you, it worked after I figured everything out!